# Bluetooth shield/module for file transfer?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm currently working on a project that requires to display images on a touchscreen on my arduino. These images are neither stored in arduino nor any memory card. I want to be able to send the images via Bluetooth from an app and display it on the touchscreen. The problem is I couldn't find a good and solid Bluetooth shield or module that provide file transfer via bluetooth from an iOS app to arduino. If you can name a few bluetooh shields or modules that'd be great. In the thread below, someone claimed hc-05 works. Can anyone support that claim? Thanks.
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=208306.0

Comment: Bluetooth shields do (mostly) not have built-in file-transfer support. For the reason  that Microcontrollers (mostly) don't have file-systems. You could however, write your own protocol, or directly store the characters you get and attempt to display that as an image.

For projects with: images/camera/filesystems/USB I would recommend using a raspberry PI.

Comment: where you successful in transferring text file over bluetooth to your android app???? if yes, then can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an HC-05 (or HC-06 - there seems to be little difference) - You will need to do your own file transfer protocol - for small images, zmodem or xmodem (usual file-over-serial) are probably completely overly complex. You would also need your own app for the phone.

Alternatively, you could use a network (ethernet or wifi) addon on your arduino - I think I read the Arduino Yun has built in ethernet and wifi.http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer has a webserver, this could be adapted to accept uploaded files. You can then use a webbrowser on your phone (or indeed anywhere else!) to send the files. If you want to send from outside your local network, you may need to set up port forwarding on your router (google: port forward) - the port you want to forwards is 80.

Comment: I'm going to go with the first approach but using a different bluetooth module. I'm already using bluetooth to talk with my iPad; i want to keep the cost down so I'd decided not to use WIFI. Thanks for the tips.